# side effects of virtual public class in C++

Tags: c++, class, virtual

[Virtual Public Class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr135.htm) is used for a class to ensure that an object of a class inherits only one  subobject.

```
class L { /* ... */ }; // indirect base class
class B1 : virtual public L { /* ... */ };
class B2 : virtual public L { /* ... */ };
class D : public B1, public B2 { /* ... */ }; // valid
```

Do we have side effect when we use virtual public when we don't use it for single inheritance. For example, is

```
class L { /* ... */ }; // indirect base class
class B1 : virtual public L { /* ... */ };
class D : public B1 { /* ... */ }; // valid
```

the same as

```
class L { /* ... */ }; // indirect base class
class B1 : public L { /* ... */ };
class D : public B1 { /* ... */ }; // valid
```

? I mean, is it just safe to make the parent class as virtual for all possible cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just as safe to make the parent class virtual "just in case." The standard doesn't specify how virtual inheritance will be implemented, but there will probably be a slight performance hit. Unless you're writing something performance-critical, you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html

> classes needed to be extended with one or more virtual pointers, and a simple attribute lookup in an object now needs two indirections through the virtual table

Not unlike virtual functions.